# Remove CSS Class Depending on Screen Size jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a selector attached to an image element that provides the function of a magnifier glass for the image. I need to remove the selector, so it no longer initiates the magnifier, and then re-add it, depending on screen size. So for instance, when accessed in a mobile screen, I would like the class removed. If screen size adjusts upward of 480px, then I would like the class re-added. What is the best, and most efficient way to approach this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [**What have you tried**](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Show some code and the let them be revised...

Comment: So far, I have used innerWidth and resize() to try to ascertain the window size, and using an if statement to create the action depending on the window size. So something like this - though I am not sure this is the best way to do it(?):
 
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth ==< 480) {
    // add selector code
    } else if (window.innerWidth > 480) {
    // remove selector code
    }
}).resize();

Comment: Did you see my answer bellow?... similar to what you have tried... Then it should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind jQuery, a simple Example might do the trick:

CSS:

```
.red{
background:red;
}

.yellow{
background:yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width:300px; height:100px;" class="yellow"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

$(window).bind("resize",function(){
    console.log($(this).width())
    if($(this).width() <500){
    $('div').removeClass('yellow').addClass('red')
    }
    else{
    $('div').removeClass('red').addClass('yellow')
    }
})
})
```

This will change the color of the div element whenever you resize the containing window.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6v7GE/

*NOTE: In fiddle resizing is sliding the  holders of the containing window.*

Comment: Thanks @ErickBest - your solution looks much better than what I had come up with. I will accept your answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: Sure, enjoy your coding!

Answer (score 1):

Some Suggestions I would have is @media Queries Using multiple style sheets (They apply different css based on the screen size) OR to apply either java-script or a java-script library.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />

<!-- CSS media query within a style sheet -->
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {

      if ($(this).width() < 1024) {
        $('.div').hide();
      } else {
        $('.divNew').show();
      }

});
```

With this code you can hide the div depending on the width.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use media queries?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries

They were designed to handle such situations.

Comment: Should you wish to have a post downVoted, Please explain the reason why you are downvoting.

Comment: I don't think media queries can remove/re-add a selector from an element. Can they? BTW I didn't down-vote your answer, I'm not sure who did?

Comment: @Lea  : it doesn't matter who downvoted :). Media queries can't remove or add selectors, but they allow you to have different set of values/dimensions depending on the device, so that in many situations less JavaScript code is needed to handle the differences.